I've heard of a term for something beyond the boundaries of human thought. What does the term sound like and whether it exists at all
I've heard of a term for something beyond the boundaries of human thought. That is, there is something a person can think about and there is something that is behind. What does the term sound like and whether it exists at all.

You might be thinking of Kant's distinction between the appearance (what we can think) and the thing-in-itself, which is beyond possible thought.

if you subscribe to fodors LOTH, this is perhaps "ineffable".

Philosophers call it "limits of thought". Cusanus, Kant, Hegel, Wittgenstein discussed them. In recent times, Bayne has a chapter The limits of thought in his text on thinking, and Priest wrote a whole book about it, Beyond the Limits of Thought.

Kant's concept and elaboration of "the transcendental" concerns all that "transcends" human experience in detail and as such. Human experience, or human consciousness (or thought, if you will), is a third body between the world of the thing in itself and the world of the demands of reason, both of which are forever transcendent to it in the Kantian view. This is a continuance of Plato's tripartism, one can note, Kant being an attempt to justify and account for the role of reason only in human life.

I'd like to give a few options:

@emesupap suggested 'ineffable'. To me this means it cannot be expressed, communicated about. But there I think there are instances where one has a thought (cognitive experience) but cannot describe/explain - for example, in hypnogogic states.  I do see however that sometimes in philosophy ineffable despite its etymology can means things beyond conceiving.  Which leads to...
Inconceivable....and...
The unthinkable - this is something used in philosophy contexts, but it can, in everyday speech include a negative sense of something terrible.
Noumenon or the plural Noumena - which @David Gudeman essentially brought up with things-in-themselves. I'd say here the focus is on the we can't think correctly about that and/or with any confidence, given it is beyond the empirical. There might be something 'out there' but we have no access to it or way to sense it or draw conclusions about it. I'd say there's more focus on epistemology, here, then my sense of the goal of the question.

I'd vote for 'inconceivable'. Here one can not only not utter something about it (ineffable), but further cannot even conceive of it (think of it).

"The transcendent" (or "transcendental") is another word used for this (like "ineffable", "the mystical"). E.g. as used in Wittgenstein's Tractatus: 6.13 "Logic is  mirror image of the world. Logic is transcendental", 6.421 "It's clear that ethics is ineffable. Ethics is transcendental."

@mudskipper I very much suspect Wittgenstein - even the early one - would never have said that humans cannot have ethical thought. Just that it isn't conceived in terms of language. After all, the "world" he is speaking about here is that of which experience can be shared via language.

@PhilipKlöcking - I agree. I have the impression Wittgenstein himself was obsessed by ethics. But the question is how do the limits of language relate to the limits of thought. This is not at all cleared up in the Tractatus - there seems to be a constant equivocation between "thought" (der Gedanke) and "language" (der Satz); and he does explicitly identify those two -- perhaps against his better human-all-too-human instincts in :)

The saying/showing distinction is at play here imo. The early Wittgenstein might/could have said that "thought" is totally irrelevant for ethics (similar to his remarks about the "good or bad will"); ethical value "shows itself" in action, in a way of life, similar to how logical validity "shows itself" in valid arguments. The essence of both is ineffable - cannot be described or grasped in language - but since it cannot be described clearly it can also not be grasped in thought. It can at most be pointed at. (I think Ws view is too absolutist, but this is how I read the Tract.)

What is the word for "something beyond the boundaries of human thought"?
Several words are used that mean more or less the same as "something beyond the boundaries of human thought". The most important, I think, are:

transcendent, transcendental ("transcendent" literally means "going beyond", "what has gone beyond")
inconceivable ("what cannot be comprehended, understood, grasped")
ineffable ("what cannot be uttered in words", "what cannot be described")
mystical (usually suggests a direct, unsharable experience in a religious context)

The phrase "something beyond the boundaries of human thought" has itself a paradoxical ring to it. It seems to point to "something beyond the boundaries of human thought", but if it actually did refer to "that", doesn't that imply that "that" is not beyond our boundaries? Is that phrase itself coherent? Can every "thing" that we can somehow point to also be grasped?

In the Proslogion Anselm of Canterbury based his proof of God's existence on the definition of "God" as "that compared to which anything greater can not be thought" (id quo maius cogitari nequit). This concept "clearly" seems to point to "something" beyond any of our thoughts. But, according to Anselm, we have that concept. And it is "greater" to think of something as existing than to consider it as not existing; it's greater to exist than not to exist. So, according to Anselm, the concept implies existence, and we can only conceive God as existing. (For a very interesting analysis of this argument, see Paul E. Oppenheimer and Edward Zalta's On the Logic of the Ontological Argument.)

Philosophers don't always seem to appreciate that our "thinking about thinking" is often (I'd say inevitably) guided by metaphors and analogies.  Metaphors that derive from everyday, very basic actions and perceptions. The two metaphors that seem to me most basic are "pointing" and "grasping". Another one is "digesting". (Do I know or understand something if I can point to it? Do I need to be able to grasp it -- and hold it, so it doesn't escape or break? Do I also need to digest it?) It's interesting to see that these metaphors are transcultural (as might be expected). You can then also ask yourself which metaphors are "behind" various thoughts about the ineffable or the transcendent. -- One is of course the metaphor of something "hidden" - with all its ramifications: "hide-and-seek", "revelation", "discovery". It seems that Heidegger is trying to describe this in his phenomenology of the "clearing". The visual metaphors of "light" versus "dark", "clarity", "clear and distinct ideas", also immediately appear - and these are also transcultural. See for instance the first chapter of the Laozi (trans. is my own; following Ziporyn and the Mawangdui text) that speaks of an ineffable Way:
A way that can be traced is not the constant way
A name that can be named is not the constant name

Without name - the beginning of Heaven and Earth
With name - mother of the ten thousand things

Therefore - 
Constantly without desire - to observe its minuteness
Constantly with desire - to observe its cries

These two are the same in source, differ in name
The same - call it "dark"

In darkness - a deeper darkness
The gate of all mystery

One more question here is how any limits of language relate to the limits of thought. If we can point to something (using language), can we then also grasp it (understand it)? If something can not be described in language, can we think it or have a conception of it (in a broad, unspecified sense of that word)? -- In a very mundane sense, of course we can. I know how a screeching violin sounds, and I just pointed to that phenomenon, but I cannot really describe it except as by saying "like a screeching violin". In a trivial sense every perceived physical object or event is also "something beyond thought", since "it itself" is not "in" our thoughts. -- If you've ever known synaesthetic perceptions, you know how ineffable those seem to be; I can describe their modalities, but it seems impossible to make them shareable to others just by using words. But strangely enough, we do understand some analogies. To a blind person I might say that the color brown in contrast to bright yellow is more like a a deep, low boom, as in "Oompah-loompah", and bright yellow more like a higher pitched sharp sound, as in "shreek". (See for instance Color and Sound. Physical and Psychophysical Relations for a quick overview.) This is the stuff of poetry. To quote from Marianne Moore's bundle Nevertheless (1944):
THE MIND IS AN ENCHANTING THING
 
is an enchanted thing
     like the glaze on a
katydid-wing
         subdivided by sun
         till the nettings are legion.
Like Gieseking playing Scarlatti;

like the apteryx-awl
     as a beak, or the
kiwi's rain shawl
         of haired feathers, the mind
         feeling its way as though blind,
walks along with its eyes on the ground.

It has memory's ear
     that can hear without
having to hear.
         Like the gyroscope's fall,
         truly unequivocal
because trued by regnant certainty,  

it is a power of
      strong enchantment. It
is like the dove-
           neck animated by
           sun; it is memory’s eye;
it’s conscientious inconsistency.

It tears off the veil; tears
      the temptation, the
mist the heart wears,
           from its eyes -- if the heart
           has a face; it takes apart
dejection. It's fire in the dove-neck's

iridescence; in the 
     inconsistencies
of Scarlatti.
           Unconfusion submits
           its confusion to proof; it's
not a Herod's oath that cannot change.

(Marianne Moore, Complete Poems, Faber & Faber, London 1967)
In a less trivial sense the concept of (perceived, determinate) object is an ideal, the Kantian "Ding-an-Sich", it's the limit of anything determinable (measurable, perceivable). So, we never fully know what any "thing" is and any "thing-as-it-is-in-itself" will always be "beyond our (complete) grasp". But it's unclear if we need to assume these kind of transcendental limits of thought. Since, what sense does it make to speak of a limit, if we cannot really see (or go) beyond it? (We're again battling with metaphors,
in this case spatial metaphors: "in", "out", "limit", "border". Philosophy doesn't seem to be able to go beyond those...)

The advent of thinking machines with superhuman capabilities has given an interesting and very concrete new twist to the question whether some things might be "beyond our understanding". Here we do seem to reach our limit, and we know about it, since something else seems to go beyond it. Programs like AlphaGo -- or its successors -- have demonstrated superhuman strength, and not by "simple" brute computing power but by playing creatively. It's not completely clear, I think, if humans cannot still catch up, but it's conceivable that the Go game itself is just too deep for us. (Note that the large branching factor of the game contributes to that, of course, but is not at all sufficient to make this game "deep".) At the same time, it's interesting to see that there has been a jump in strength of professional players - not just because they are learning from the AIs (trying to catch up), but because they are inventing new moves at a faster  rate as well. (See a sketched framework for how to think about the cultural impact of the interactions with intelligent machines, see for instance, Levin Brinkman, a.o. Machine Culture, 2023.)

Poetry looks better typeset like this

@Rushi - Thanks for the tip. I don't like the italics in this case; I would like a different font though. Is there a way to do so too?

Just don't use the * ... *. I was pointing out that the indents can be forced with nbsp-s. If you try to edit that question you can see. This problem with the code formatting is it becomes unreadable on a phone screen
